# Detect mouse over nsbezierpath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse, mouseover, nsbezierpath

I'm a starting developer and I have this single window Mac application with a custom view inside. Inside that custom ceix I have defined multiple nsbezierpath. 
Each nsbezierpath represents a region of my map so they are not rectangular at all.

What I would like to have is a way to detect when my mouse enter a nsbezierpath so that I could display the name of the region over which the mouse is hovering.

I can't seem to find where to start, any ideas ?

Thanks for looking into my problem

Comment: Do you know how to get the mouse position and hit test the bezier? What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I tried adding the mouseMoved method but it doesn't get triggered at all. So I figure I'm missing something but I don't know what.
I do know however how to get the location in view when mouseDown is triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a [tracking area](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html) to detect mouse movement (`NSTrackingArea`). Be sure that the mouse location is in the view coordinate system, then use the location in a call to `containsPoint:` on each bezier path to determine which ones the mouse is over.